# What determines if an iOS app gets the new look in iOS 7

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7

What exactly does iOS 7 use to determine whether the application should be displayed with the traditional iOS 6 style UI (aka iOS6 compatibility mode), or the newer iOS 7 UI?

- If I build our app in Xcode 5, with base SDK set to 7 I get the iOS 7 UI as expected
- If I build our app in Xcode 5, with base SDK set to 6 I still get the iOS 7 UI (unexpected, happens on real device and simulator)
- If I build in Xcode 4.x, I get the older UI as expected

In all cases, the deployment target is set to 5.

Since our app has fairly custom UI we're not ready to move to the new look of iOS 7 yet.  However we do need to make some backend changes to support iOS 7 which we need to release now.  Can we still submit apps built with Xcode 4.x and expect them to be accepted?

Comment: doesn't it depends on what os is on the simulator/device ?

Comment: Yes you can sumbit app with xcode 4.6 on app store

Comment: I want the iOS 7 UI, but it don't work. I build my app in xCode 5, with base SDK set to 7, deployment target set to 6. But my app just don't get the iOS 7 UI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the time being, you are able to.  Apple will make an announcement when they stop accepting apps built with Xcode 4.x.  My company is currently submitting apps with Xcode 4.6 since we do not have a new enough operating system for 5.  I suspect it will be at least a few months until they stop.

Answer (score 2):

Running against 6.1 Base SDK should do it.

However, as I discovered yesterday. Anything less than 7.0 Base SDK isn't supported by Xcode 5 (officially) and so it is undefined behaviour.

My app suddenly switched from iOS6 UI to iOS7 UI with no code changes.

In the end I restarted my mac and phone, deleted the app, deleted derived data and reinstalled cocoapods and it was working on iOS6 UI again.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you set the Base SDK to iOS 6 in both the Project build settings & the target build settings - that should do the trick. Even though the target settings are supposed to override the project, I found that when just the target was set to 6 - it compiled with 7.

Regarding XCode 5, it's true that it doesn't officially ship with the iOS 6 SDK. However, you can extract it from XCode 4.6 and use it in 5.
You'll find the SDK in the XCode app under:
Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs

Simply copy it from an existing installation of XCode 4.6 or from its .dmg (which can still be downloaded from Apple's website) to the corresponding folder in XCode 5, restart and you should now be able to select it as the Base SDK. Note that you'll have to do this after every update of XCode so you might find it easier to use a symbolic link rather than copying.

We've successfully submitted apps built this way to the App Store although as has been said before me, it would be a good idea to transition to iOS 7 ASAP before Apple makes it compulsory.